# Android Alert Dialog in 2.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

How do i customize alert dialog like [GTasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dayup.gtask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom dialog box and make it as you want.
Yes you can change your Dialog box as you want.You can do this by creating a custom dialog box.
 Step1.Create a style in String file in res

```
<style name="myQuitDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog"> 
   <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>

    </style>
```

Step2. Create the xml file in layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_quit"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/image which u want to show"
 >
```

Step3. Write code of custom dialog box in src

```
    class Custom_Dialog extends Dialog {

        protected Custom_Dialog(Context context, int theme) {
            super(context, theme);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    }
private void show_alert() {
        final Custom_Dialog alertbox = new Custom_Dialog(this, R.style.myQuitDialog);
        Window window = alertbox.getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        window.requestFeature(window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        alertbox.show(); 
        alertbox.setCancelable(true);
        alertbox.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


                 alertbox.dismiss();
            }



    }
```

This is all what you need and accept it if you feel it satisfied you.

Comment: Thanks for your help i have found a following Github Repo which will help you to customize alert dialog, button, edittext etc.


  [1]: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Comment: Then what i will do with this @DineshAnandan. The above is the same thing to create a custom dialog box which you needed

Comment: I agree with you but i need ICS UI so I used the Github Repo. Your help much appreciated.

Comment: if you to really appreciate me then you can accept or vote my answer

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

http://mgmblog.com/2010/06/10/arrayadapter-and-alertdialog-for-single-choice-items/